# java.lang.AbstractMethodError in implementing Spock-Reports Extension (renatoathaydes) for my SPOCK test

Tags: spock, spock-reports, jenkins-spock

I'm very new to SPOCK so excuse me if this a silly question.
I've done report setup in my Maven based Spock-Groovy project as mentioned in the below git-hub project-
https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports

What I've done is-

1. Added below 3 Mvn Dependencies to my POM:

   com.athaydes
      spock-reports
      2.0-RC2
      test
      
      
        
          *
          *
        
      
    
    
    
      org.slf4j
      slf4j-api
      1.7.30
      test
    
    
      org.slf4j
      slf4j-simple
      1.7.30
      test
2. Added report Config.groovy to src/test/groovy path as below-

   spockReports {
   // set all properties at once
   set( [ 'com.athaydes.spockframework.report.showCodeBlocks': true,
   'com.athaydes.spockframework.report.outputDir': 'target/spock-reports' ] )
   }

Now as per above git instruction results should be generated with index.html in my target/spock-reports directory but I'm getting below exception while running the test.
Not able to understand what shall I do to fix this error!

I've also tried by changing to latest versions of above dependencies i.e.- **2.0.0-alpha1**, but no help :(
Note: However everything was working fine before above two changes.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.SpockReportsConfiguration does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:190)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyTryThese(Closure.java:313)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getPropertyOwnerFirst(Closure.java:307)
at groovy.lang.Closure.getProperty(Closure.java:296)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I surprisingly got it working today, by changing versions to the older stable (1.7.1) for spock-reports and latest one: '2.0.0-alpha1' for - slf4j dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>*</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```